# set date from one year of getdate ()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function, getdate

I got a `DECLARE` statement like this

```
DECLARE ,@ACTIVATE DATETIME,
        @DEACTIVATE DATETIME
```

I want to set the `Activate` date as today's date, which is

```
SET @ACTIVATE = GETDATE()
```

I want to set the `@DEACTIVATE` date to one year from the `Activate` date.

```
 ACTIVATE = 30/07/2018
 DEACTIVATE = 30/07/2019
```

I can set `DEACTIVATE` date using string, but is there any other function or method to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DATEADD` function:

```
SET @Deactivate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @Activate)
```